# Python - Tuples - Retrieve unique elements in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, unique

UPDATE:

I went with this:

```
set(item[1] for item in id)
```

Thanks guys, your ideas helped me.

---

I am working with a list of tuples:

Using the following line of code as an example. My list can be of any lenght. However, I will always be looking for a given index of my tuples:

```
id = [(9,'Tup','Check'),(10,'Tup','Pyton'),(11,'Not Tup','Stack'),(12,'Not Tup','Stack')]
```

In this scenario, I am looking to grab the unique second elements.

```
objective_ouput = ('Tup','Not Tup')
```

Comment: What did you try so far and where did you get stuck? Please note that SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Try using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to obtain a list of the elements you want and then look at how you could use [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: Ok thanks, will let you guys know.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered (the check mark next to a response) if you feel it has been answered completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It as simple as follow:

```
objective_ouput_set = {item[1] for item in id}
```

Comment: Used this: set(item[1] for item in id) - Thanks guys, your ideas helped me.

Comment: @ruh adapted to your choice ;)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Happens also with `list()` vs `[]`, and `dict()` vs `{}` dont really know why. [Here](https://ideone.com/4ZP6Rz)

Comment: @JoseA. That's a very different issue, though. Doesn't involve any comprehensions or generators. You really shouldn't write `...` there. And better don't measure it in the same benchmark at all. And don't use such low and different `number` values.

Comment: @StefanPochmann You are right, I hope [this one](https://ideone.com/9HCud8) fulfills your requirements. Still my point is that "constant" (nothing to do with the list comprehension) initialization is much faster in the literal way that the function way. This reduces readability if you want performance IMO.

Comment: @JoseA. Ok that's better, although I still wouldn't trust such very small times, and find it a bit odd to have non-empty set constructions alongside empty dict/list constructions. Anyway, the speed difference between for example `[]` and `list()` is because `[]` is much more direct and built-in. Disassemble them and compare how they're handled: https://ideone.com/E69D4C

Comment: How many 0s do you want there? Well, I don't know how to make an empty set outside of `set()` since `{}` gives a dict. Is the handling of arguments what takes the time? Can a lookup and a call make a ~4.5x difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
tup = ()
tuple([t[1] for t in your_list_of_tuples if t[1] not in tup])
```

By the way, `id` is not a good variable name because it is a builtin.

Answer (score 1):

By zipping the tuples together you get a series of tuples at each index. Combine this with `set()` to eliminate duplicates then;

```
[set(tup) for tup in zip(*id))]
```

will generate a list containing unique elements at each index.